# how to play SWF file in wxwidgets using wxMediaCtrl

Tags: flash, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I want to play swf file in wxWidgets using wxMediaCtrl. so i'm search on internet and found this link [wxMediaCtrl backend for flash.ocx](http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10981&p=49276&hilit=wxmediactrl%20swf#p49276). and then i install the adobe shockwaveflash and and also adobe flash, and implemented on mysample project, but it's not showing the wxMediaCtrl play swf file. 
(Sorry for my english before), now i'm using codeblocks 10_05 and wxWidgets-2.8.12, so this is my code :

code on LLS_MediaPlay.h

```
#include "wx/mediactrl.h"
#include "wx/msw/ole/activex.h" // wxActiveXContainer
#include "wx/msw/ole/automtn.h" // wxAutomationObject

const IID IID_Flash = {0xD27CDB6C,0xAE6D,0x11CF,{0x96,0xB8,0x44,0x45,0x53,0x54,0x00,0x00}};
const CLSID CLSID_Flash = {0xD27CDB6E,0xAE6D,0x11cf,{0x96,0xB8,0x44,0x45,0x53,0x54,0x00,0x00}};
class WXDLLIMPEXP_MEDIA wxFlashMediaBackend : public wxMediaBackendCommonBase
{
public:
wxFlashMediaBackend() : m_pAX(NULL) {}
virtual ~wxFlashMediaBackend()
{
    if(m_pAX)
    {
        m_pAX->DissociateHandle();
        delete m_pAX;
    }
}

virtual bool CreateControl(wxControl* ctrl, wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style, const wxValidator& validator, const wxString& name)
{
    IDispatch* pDispatch;
    if( ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Flash, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_Flash, (void**)&pDispatch) != 0)
        return false;

    m_PDF.SetDispatchPtr(pDispatch); // wxAutomationObject will release itself

    if (!ctrl->wxControl::Create(parent, id, pos, size,(style & ~wxBORDER_MASK) | wxBORDER_NONE, validator, name))
        return false;
    m_ctrl = wxStaticCast(ctrl, wxMediaCtrl);
    m_pAX = new wxActiveXContainer(ctrl, IID_Flash, pDispatch);
    wxFlashMediaBackend::ShowPlayerControls(wxMEDIACTRLPLAYERCONTROLS_NONE);
    return true;
}

virtual bool Play()
{
    return true;
}

virtual bool Pause()
{
    return true;
}

virtual bool Stop()
{
    return true;
}

virtual bool Load(const wxString& filename)
{
    m_PDF.CallMethod(_T("LoadFile"),"1",filename);
    NotifyMovieLoaded();
    wxSizeEvent event;
    m_pAX->OnSize(event);
    return true;
}

virtual bool Load(const wxURI& location)
{
    return m_PDF.CallMethod(_T("LoadFile"), location.BuildUnescapedURI()).GetBool();
}

virtual bool Load(const wxURI& WXUNUSED(location), const wxURI& WXUNUSED(proxy))
{
    return false;
}

virtual wxMediaState GetState()
{
    return wxMEDIASTATE_STOPPED;
}

virtual bool SetPosition(wxLongLong where)
{
    m_PDF.CallMethod(_T("setCurrentPage"), wxVariant((long)where.GetValue()));
    return true;
}

virtual wxLongLong GetPosition()
{
    return 0;
}

virtual wxLongLong GetDuration()
{
    return 0;
}

virtual void Move(int WXUNUSED(x), int WXUNUSED(y), int WXUNUSED(w), int WXUNUSED(h))
{

}

virtual wxSize GetVideoSize() const
{
    return wxDefaultSize;
}

virtual double GetPlaybackRate()
{
    return 0;
}

virtual bool SetPlaybackRate(double)
{
    return false;
}

virtual double GetVolume()
{
    return 0;
}

virtual bool SetVolume(double)
{
    return false;
}

virtual bool ShowPlayerControls(wxMediaCtrlPlayerControls flags)
{
    if(flags)
    {
        m_PDF.CallMethod(_T("setShowToolbar"), true);
        m_PDF.CallMethod(_T("setShowScrollbars"), true);
    }
    else
    {
        m_PDF.CallMethod(_T("setShowToolbar"), false);
        m_PDF.CallMethod(_T("setShowScrollbars"), false);
    }
    return true;
}
wxActiveXContainer* m_pAX;
wxAutomationObject m_PDF;

DECLARE_DYNAMIC_CLASS(wxFlashMediaBackend)
};

 class LLS_MediaPlay: public wxFrame
 {
public:

    LLS_MediaPlay(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id=wxID_ANY);
    virtual ~LLS_MediaPlay();
    void OnplayvideoButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
    wxMediaCtrl *mediaplayer;

    //(*Declarations(LLS_MediaPlay)
    //*)

protected:

    //(*Identifiers(LLS_MediaPlay)
    //*)

private:

    //(*Handlers(LLS_MediaPlay)
    //*)
    static const long ID_MEDIACTRL1;


    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
 };
```

and this code on LLS_MediaPlay.cpp :

```
 mediaplayer = new wxMediaCtrl(this, ID_MEDIACTRL1, _T("G:\\hendy\\animation\\gas.swf"), wxPoint(5,5), wxSize(1000,400), 0, _T("wxFlashMediaBackend"), wxDefaultValidator, _T("SWF Player"));

Connect(ID_MEDIACTRL1, wxEVT_MEDIA_PLAY, (wxObjectEventFunction)&LLS_MediaPlay::OnplayvideoButtonClick);

 void LLS_MediaPlay::OnplayvideoButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
 {
     // is it mediaplayer->Show(); ??
 }
```

there's no error when i compile this code **BUT** not showing the wxFlashMediaBackend play the gas.swf file. it's showing a empty whiteframe but if i right click on that frame, it will showing popupmenu **About Adobe Flash Player 11.8.800.94...**

can anyone tell me where i'm doing the mistake?

i really want to show my empty whiteframe image, but i don't have 10 reputation for showing that image. sorry for that. but can anybody help me?
Any insight on why this is happening would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, finally i found the solution.
now i can play swf / flash file using wxwidgets-2.8.12 on codeblocks 10_05 or on codeblocks 12-11.

i'm just add this to LLS_MediaPlay.cpp :

```
Connect(ID_MEDIACTRL1, wxEVT_ACTIVEX, (wxObjectEventFunction)&LLS_MediaPlay::OnplayvideoButtonClick);
```

and OnplayvideoButtonClick method, i add this :

```
mediaplayer->Play();
```

so, just like that! now i can play my swf files in windows platform.